# what are the possible ways to create block quickly

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

I have a private blockchain network. When I send a transaction, it goes to pendingtransaction.  Once miners complete mining, it stores into the block. This process takes lots of time.

How can I store transaction quickly (within few seconds)?

1. Can we decrease time interval between blocks so that i don't need to wait?
2. Can i increase mining speed?
   Or
3. Is there another way to solve it?

Comment: Another possibility in a private blockchain is to setup a proof of authority network [Use of puppet to configure Clique PoA on Private blockchain](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/use-puppet-configure-clique-poa-private-blockchain-ajay-singh). You can set a lower time between blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can mine new blocks faster by changing the `difficulty` parameters of your `customGenesis.json` to a lower value. Lower difficulty for blocks will make it easier to mine new blocks, which in turn will mean shorter times to mine blocks.

See [this article](https://media.consensys.net/how-to-build-a-private-ethereum-blockchain-fbf3904f337), search for `CustomGenesis.json` for list of fields available